# Testing es6 module that imports another es6 module in Jest

Tags: jestjs, es6-modules

I am trying to test some code using Jest.

I am using node v19.6.0 and jest 29.5.0.

As far as I can tell, all of my code (except for config files) and my dependencies are using es6 syntax and modules.

Here is what is happening:

- I have an es6 module A.js
- I have a jest test in es6 format, A.test.js, that imports module A
- If I remove all imports from A then the test is able to import A successfully and run the test.
- If I import another module, B, within A, then I get an error
- In A, I am using this syntax to import B `import * as B from "packagename/b.js";`
- B is a 3rd party es6 module
- When I run my code normally (not using jest) this import works fine

The error I get depends on the flags passed to node. If I pass
`NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules` then I get the error "Must use import to load ES Module:". If I remove that vm-modules flag then I get "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

If I copy the B module out of node_modules and paste it into my src, then it can be imported successfully.

My jest config looks like this:

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
}
```

I have discovered that if I change the package type to "module", and change the jest config to look like this

```
"jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "transform": {}
},
```

then the tests work, but nothing else works. Specifically, the various config files seem to be treated as modules when they use the commonjs syntax.

For now I am using the "node" jest config and adding `type : module` when I want to run tests and removing it otherwise.

What is going on? Is there a way to get jest to work without using type "module"?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm experiencing the same problem with just a custom .js file that is using import syntax. Tried everything suggested but no luck and have tried downgrading packages but same result.

Comment: @theseboys nope didn't find a solution. Still just adding and removing "type : module" as needed :(